# JavaScript Runtime : criteria to be in the `Event Queue`

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventqueue

In many examples explaining the Event Loop, they always use the `setTimeout` to illustrate it.

According to those explanations, when the JS runtime meets the `setTimeout` instruction, it knows there is a callback so it puts the instruction in the `Event Queue` so that it puts it in the `Callback Queue`.

**My questions are** : how the runtime knows if it has to put the instruction in the `Event Queue` ? does it check the parameters and if a param is a function so that means it's a callback ? what are the criteria to be in that `Event Queue` ?

Comment: Have a look @ https://vimeo.com/96425312

Comment: @KooiInc thank you. So only "webapis" functions are concerned with the Event-loop ?